# RESTful WebApi Filtered lists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have an object.

```
public class foo()
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and a set of related objects.

```
public class bar()
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int fooId{get;set}
}
```

And I want to return a list of bars with a fooId of, for example, 9.

How would I structure an ASP.Net WebApi controller to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the filter on the query string:

the url would be

```
api/bars?fooid=9
```

controller method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBars(int fooid)
```

and assuming that you've got a `BarsController` this would be covered by the default routing.

Comment: Technically speaking, is this RESTful?  That's what I can't decide.

Comment: @RichBryant - yes, check this out: http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf